# add dns record in from c#

Tags: c#, dns

How to add record in dns using c#, currently i am trying to use below code, but no luck.

[Manage DNS server by C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146270/manage-dns-server-by-c-sharp-code)

```
AddARecord("dns01.iaxus.com", "iaxus.com", "10.0.0.20", "14.145.101.55");
```

where `14.145.101.55` is my wan ip.

its throwing below error:

```
The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499050/wmi-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706ba

Comment: adding successfully from windows server itself but not from network computer.

Answer (score 0):

try running your application as administrator
if that doesn't work then try disabling your firewall and then run as administrator.

Comment: application already running as administrator and firewall also disabled but no luck.

Comment: adding successfully from windows server itself but not from network computer.